# Changing alpha of Text's CanvasGroup in OnTriggerEnter Unity

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, alpha

I'm currently working on a game that pays hommage to Marble Blast Gold/Ultra.

At this point I have text that is positioned with the marble. The text is a child of a canvas and I have a canvas group added to the text. I initially set the alpha of the canvas group to 0 so that you can't see the text.

What I'm trying to do is have it so that when you pick up a power up the text reappears by changing the canvas group's alpha back to 1 and then once the power up is used set it back to 0.

I'm not seeming to have any luck with my current code.

```
// Super Jump pickup
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Spring")
    {
        superJumpText.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        canSuperJump = true;
        canSuperSpeed = false;
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        hitSuperJump = true;
        Invoke("Display", 20);
    }

    void Update()
{

    //super jump
    if (canSuperJump)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Vector3 jump = new Vector3(0, superJumpForce, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(jump);
            canSuperJump = false;
            superJumpText.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason this would not work for you is that somewhere in your parent hierarchy you have a gameobject with another canvas group. That would ALWAYS override the child canvas group settings UNLESS you select the `'Ignore Parent Groups'` checkbox in the child canvas

[image: c]

Comment: That would make sense. I even saw that option and it never even crossed my mind. There are several other canvases on the parent object. I'll definitely check this out when I get the chance and leave some feedback on whether it works or not.